# Sending POST request to HTTPS aws server using SIM900A

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I have hooked up an SIM900A module to my Arduino UNO and I wanted to send a GET request to my aws server for which I have created a RESTful API, the problem is that when I send a request using AT commands I get 601 error code. But I am easily able to connect to https:// www.goolge.com and get the HTML page. I have seen some other links which are very much technical for me like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177095/unable-to-invoke-aws-api-gateway-get-url-with-gprs-connection and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266974/testing-a-connection-to-a-tcp-socket-through-sim5320a-cellular-module.

I want to know if SIM900A even support connections to HTTPS and if yes, how can I connect to my aws server. I kind of a noob in networking, so sorry if I cannot elaborate on details. I have read somewhere online that SIM900A only supports half https, I don't know what that means, any help/advice would be helpful.

AT commands I used

`AT
AT+CGATT = 1
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","www"
AT+SAPBR=1,1
AT+SAPBR=2,1
AT+HTTPSSL=1
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://www.google.gom"
AT+HTTPACTION=0
AT+HTTPREAD`

Comment: Did you *really* mean to include a link to `www.goolge.com`? (which I've deliberately *not* made into a link here) Or did you mean to link to Google?

Comment: @SamGibson I did not mean to link to google, I mean I was able to connect to https google, I have removed the link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975051/error-httpaction0-601-0 also, edit your question to add your code. Also check a few more https and http sites, to see if there is a pattern.

Comment: @Paul I have tried and I am able to connect to all tried HTTP sites and few HTTPS sites, I have added the code, I want to know how to connect to an AWS server.

Comment: Have you tried issuing the command AT+HTTPSSL=? to make sure your device supports SSL. You can also try the command AT+HTTPSSL=1 to force SSL on if it isn't already. You can query the current mode with AT+HTTPSSL?

Comment: Maybe the websites support HTTP fallback, but Amazon AWS doesn't? Or it uses another more advanced certificate or encryption?

Comment: @SpeedOfSpin Yes I have used AT+HTTPSS=1 before sending the request

Comment: @Paul can you please elaborate, what you have said?

Comment: There are different types of SSL, maybe your device does not support what AWS is trying to give https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/types-of-ssl-certificate/ But that's more of a guess.

Comment: @Paul Thank you, the problem is that AWS can't accept the request in SSL send by SIM module, can you put the answer with your explanation and know how to configure AWS for accepting HTTP request.

Comment: I actually have no knowledge on configuring AWS, nor do I think that it's related to Arduino (you may find better explanations on the AWS support portal). If you've found the solution, you can also post it yourself, then please note the steps that worked for you, so that others can use this information once they find themselves in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

When you use https, you must not use:

```
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://www.google.gom"
```

You must use:

```
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","www.google.gom"
```